# Scala parsing error ';' expected but string literal found

Tags: scala

what is wrong in these parsing ?

```
def role : Parser[Role] = ~> protocolID <~ "(" ~> roleName <~ ")" ~ "{" ~>      statements <~ "}" ^^ {
```

it returns an error in the first bracket : ';' expected but string literal found.

thanks,

Comment: this question is missing a lot of context.

Comment: i guess it is just a syntax error!!

Comment: Why you start with `~>` it is binary operator.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is parsed like this.

```
~>.protocolID(<~) "("...
```

That obviously doesn't make any sense. The parser bails out once it sees that string literal `"("`. It's impossible to have a string literal in that position, unless you would have a `;` after the first method call `~>.protocolID(<~)`. So that's what it tells you.

The mistake you made is trying to use the infix operator `~>` as a prefix operator.